# Cloudformation intrinsic functions in severless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I would like to use serverless to automate my cloud infrastructure

However I can not figure out how to use the intrinsic functions in serverless and I'm wondering should I switch out to cloudformation, below my problem

take this small snippet from the example aws give for dynamodb

```
WriteCapacityScalableTarget:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
  Properties:
    MaxCapacity: 15
    MinCapacity: 5
    ResourceId: !Join
      - /
      - - table
        - !Ref readings
    RoleARN: !GetAtt ScalingRole.Arn
    ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits
    ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
```

in the ResourceId I have a !Join and a !Ref. Is it correct that serverless does not have the join function below is my shot at implementing it with serverless

```
WriteCapacityScalableTarget:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
  Properties:
    MaxCapacity: 50
    MinCapacity: 5
    ResourceId: Fn::Join
      - /
      - - table
        - Fn::Ref:readings
    RoleARN:
      Fn::GetAtt
        - ScalingRole
        - Arn
    ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits
    ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
```

Any advice on how to fix this or should I go back to cloudformation and SAM work from there. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is the below snippet that you are trying to use? I think the YAML syntax format is to use "!Join" rather than "Fn::Join" When you use the 2nd snippet do you get an error ?

Comment: Both are same. !Join is the short syntax of Fn::Join. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html

Comment: @titogeo : Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: I'm trying to use bottom snippet with serverless, when I use the top in cloudformation it builds my tables, when I use serverless with the bottom snippet it doesn't error but it doesn't build my table either